# How to redirect jenkins.security.SecurityListener logs to a log file on a linux host

Tags: java, security, jenkins, logging, audit-trail

I have setup a logger on my jenkins server for jenkins.security.SecurityListener logs. I can view the logs in the webportal but I cannot find where the are stored on the server. I want to be able access these logs on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue -- wanted to redirect `jenkins.security.SecurityListener` output to a file.

In my implementation I have Jenkins running on AWS as an ECS Fargate task.  The `/var/jenkins_home` directory is mounted to an EFS filesystem.  I also have a CloudWatch agent running alongside Jenkins mounting the same EFS access point.  Any logs written to EFS can therefore be polled/monitored and transferred to CloudWatch.

The best solution I found involved installing the 'Support Core' plugin -- it automatically redirects all logs (including custom configurations in `System Log -> Log Recorders`) into `/var/jenkins_home/logs` as well as a host of additional features.

Caveat: the container logs (visible via `docker logs <container_id>`) are not written to a file by this plugin, to capture/view these outside the Jenkins UI, one of several AWS Log Drivers needs to be applied to your ECS task.

[Here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/viewing-logs/#debug-logging-in-jenkins) is the page where I found the answer.

Answer (score -1):

When you are talking about seeings logs in webportal, are you talking about console output? In that case there are some options.

For jenkins build logs,By default logs should be made available in /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log , unless customized in /etc/default/jenkins (for *.deb) or via /etc/sysconfig/jenkins (for */rpm).

Another option is to download them in your linux server using curl or wget command.

curl  http://jenkinsUrl/job/<Build_Name>/<Build_Number>/consoleText -OutFile

another common location:
${JENKINS_HOME}/jobs/${JOB_NAME}/builds/${BUILD_NUMBER}/log

You can use plugins also to capture jenkins console logs and store them in any location in server as per your choice. Plugins are available for that.

Thanks,
Subhadeep